# UIPasteboard - copy a few string from other app at one time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, uipasteboard

In an app called 'A', I copyed three strings to system pasteboard at different times. how can I copy them to my app at once.

1. go to safari copy a string: “a”
2. then still in the safari, copy another string: “ab”
3. go to my app. I already know I can get string “ab” very easy, just like you said. but I want to get both “a” and “ab”.

I konw an app called 'Pin' can store the pasteboard history items.how does it do that?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should see more [UIPasteboard doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipasteboard#1654275)

> var strings: [String]?
>   An array of strings in all pasteboard items.

Usage:

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().strings = ["hello", "www.abc.com"]
```

Comment: allow me to describe my question again

1. go to safari copy a string: “a”
2. then still in the safari, copy another string: “ab”
3. go to my app. I already know I can get string “ab” very easy, just like you said. but I want to get both “a” and “ab”.

any idea?